# TMUX keeps asking my ssh passphrase since I updated to Sierra (macOS)

Tags: mac, ssh, tmux

Just updated to MacOS Sierra and I've followed the prescribed fixes for what Apple broke with SSH and the keychain as detailed here ([macOS keeps asking my ssh passphrase since I updated to Sierra](https://superuser.com/questions/1127067/macos-keeps-asking-my-ssh-passphrase-since-i-updated-to-sierra))

Still, I can't seem to get my TMUX session to not need the passphrase, and it doesn't seem to be environment variable related either FYI.

Any thoughts from the community?

`Darwin i386 | tmux 2.3 | screen-256color`

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround by running these two commands in the window that I'd like to use to push to git. Entering my public key passphrase once allows me to push with authentication as long as I keep the window open.

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
```

Not a solution, per se, but it works for now.