# How to change macos 10.13.3 ssh passphrase for ~/.ssh/id_rsa?

Tags: macos, ssh, keychain

I've recently restored my MacBook Pro 2011 to a new machine. Things are generally getting back to working order, running 10.13.3. However, when I use ssh I am being asked for my passphrase each time.

I have tried to use [macOS keeps asking my ssh passphrase since I updated to Sierra](https://superuser.com/questions/1127067/macos-keeps-asking-my-ssh-passphrase-since-i-updated-to-sierra/1127520#1127520) and looked up existing passphrase using https://superuser.com/a/1140285/657663 without success. Tried changing the passphrase, but I still get 
$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Bad passphrase, try again for /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa:

Suggestions?

Comment: Is the problem that it asks you for the passphrase each time, or that it does this and you don't know the passphrase?

Comment: Objective is to make it so I never am asked for passphrase. Current hurdle to solving this is that the passphrase entered for ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa that I retrieve for ~/.ssh/id_rsa from Keychain Access app doesn't work.

Comment: So have you been able to successfully use id_rsa without the agent at all/ have the passphrase somewhere else?

Comment: I've not been successful since restoring the system in ssh'ing in using my id_rsa to servers where it used to work. I am asked for the id_rsa passphrase, I provide one, it then asks for my user's linux password for the server I am ssh'ing to. :(