# Mojave SSH failure

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, macos-mojave

I have some weird issues regarding SSH access. I just reinstalled a brand new Mac with macOS Mojave.

After configuring my SSH keys, I can connect to both of my Linux servers (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04). Connection via terminal without password runs without any problems however, when I try to use other software to connect, the connection fails.

My pub key is added to the Ubuntu `authorized_keys`, user matches etc. I still have my previous laptop, running Mojave and SSH without any problem.

I tried setting up an SSH connection with robo3T, commanderOne and cyberduck. All of these fail while terminal succeeds.

Don't know where to search for this problem?

#### UPDATE

After a long search, I copied private and public keys from my previous laptop, which seems to be a solution to the problem. I'm still curious about why terminal connection works and third party apps don't.

Comment: Can you post some messages or indications of the error?  Its hard to diagnose with the limited information,

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your new keys have a password on the key itself and the ones you copied from your old machine do not. Other applications don’t know the password and so can’t use the key. I think you can use the KeyChain for the password to avoid this problem but since High Sierra you have to turn that on yourself by [updating your SSH config](https://superuser.com/a/1158050/585614).